# vnc4server on Ubuntu server won't let me log in

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, vncserver

I've set up vnc4server on an ubuntu server, and installed xfce4.
Even though the vnc server starts (with or without a few X11 warnings), it won't let me connect!

Is there a setting somewhere that prevents anyone from logging in?

Here's the log file:

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb  5 2012 20:04:02
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Tue Mar 20 13:23:20 2012
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5900
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!

xfwm4-WARNING **: The display does not support the XRender extension.

xfwm4-WARNING **: The display does not support the XComposite extension.

xfwm4-WARNING **: The display does not support the XDamage extension.

xfwm4-WARNING **: The display does not support the XFixes extension.

xfwm4-WARNING **: Compositing manager disabled.

GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.31.20/./gobject/gvalue.c:185: cannot initialize GValue with type `gint', the value has already been initialized as `gint'

GLib-WARNING **: (/build/buildd/glib2.0-2.31.20/./glib/gerror.c:390):g_error_new_valist: runtime check failed: (domain != 0)

xfwm4-WARNING **: Failed to connect to session manager: Kon geen verbinding maken met de sessiebeheerder: SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined
```

And ps is letting me know it's still running:

```
17341 pts/3    S      0:00 Xvnc4 :0 -desktop barabas:0 (skerit) -auth /home/skerit/.Xauthority -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /home/skerit/.vnc/passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

What a silly cause! The tutorial I followed told me to start it like this:

```
su skerit -c 'vnc4server :0 -geometry 1024x768 --localhost'
```

Removing the localhost part solved it.